# Hovering a table row with rgba opacity not working

Tags: css, hover

When I hover the table row, instead of the hover color being a darker version of the row's color, it's constantly a gray one.

[Code example](https://jsbin.com/hicoqibiye/edit?html,css,output)

What am I missing?

```css
tr:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gray">
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="red">
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the background with another one on hover. Instead, You need to add another layer on the top of the initial background.

example where you add a background image on the top of the background-color where the background image is also a color:

```css
tr:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gray">
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="red">
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you just explained xD. But it works! Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan on hover you are erasing the previous background with another background. You should instead add another background layer on the top of the previous

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an inset shadow to darken your background color or image.

```css
tr:hover {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gray">
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="red">
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Any color can be used , even a mix of them : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wouBe (demo with few rgba()  colors)